# Default model in chat-based notebooks

Tags: chatai

In the chat-based notebooks, one can choose the model (GPT-3.5 or GPT-4) in the chat cell's advanced settings, which defaults to GPT-3.5.

[image]

**How can I change the default LLM model to GPT-4?**

Comment: Related https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2950582

Comment: I asked ChatGPT to solve this problem, it gave me "SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 "ChatSettings" -> {"Engine" -> "GPT-4"}]" but this did not work.